# Simple, forwarding-only MTA?

Tags: email, smtp, email-server

I have a domain and a server. I’d like to have some e-mail addresses on the domain and I’d like to forward them elsewhere. I’d love to avoid running a full-featured MTA on the server, since they’re complex beasts and there are many things that can go wrong. Is there a simple MTA that would only forward the e-mails for me? I imagine something that I’d just give a list of accepted e-mail addresses and the targets to forward them to.

Comment: Exim4 is pretty easy to configure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 'real' MTA (like postfix) can be simple to configure if you just need aliases : create your /etc/aliases file and do a `newaliases`. At least, you must think about spams if you forward them to a big ISP because your IP can be detect as spammer.

Comment: The problem with “real” MTAs is that I don’t understand SMTP enough to be sure I have turned off everything that could be harmful. Also, the attack surface is much larger than in the hypothetical specialized MTA. But the spam point is a very good one, it makes the whole idea too fragile to be usable.